# Wildcard subdomain priority for Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to use the functionality of `dispatch.xml` to route my request by subdomain and create a default module which will receive all the non specified subdomain.

I explain myself:

Let's say I have 3 differents modules:

- Module 1 routed from: `m1.myapp.com`
- Module 2 routed from: `m2.myapp,com`
- Default Module routed from anything else: *.myapp.com (like: `default.myapp.com`, `*entitieName*.myapp.com`, `other.myapp.com`).

My question: is there any kind of priority mechanism that will handle first written subdomain and if and only if the subdomain called isn't in the `dispatch.xml` it will route the request to my `default` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you already have such priority mechanism - that's exactly how `dispatch.xml` works:

- the order of the dispatch rules matter, the first pattern match wins and the request will be dispatched according to that rule
- if none of the rules matches the request will be sent to the `default` service/module.

Something along these lines should do what you desire:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dispatch-entries>
    <dispatch>       
       <url>m1.myapp.com/*</url>
       <module>m1</module>
    </dispatch>
    <dispatch>       
       <url>m2.myapp.com/*</url>
       <module>m2</module>
    </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

Comment: Hi again, do you know if i can do something like that:
`<dispatch>       
       <url>myapp.com/*</url>
       <module>m1</module>
    </dispatch>
    <dispatch>       
       <url>m2.myapp.com/*</url>
       <module>m2</module>
    </dispatch>
    <dispatch>       
       <url>*.myapp.com/*</url>
       <module>m3</module>
    </dispatch>`

What I want to do is routing to default for simple call to myapp.com, or if it's a specific prefix name like m2 so routing to m2, and if it's anything else: route to m3.
Can you help me?